# Problems with psexec accepteula when using psingfo

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, psexec

I made my first script which can get and show the running time of a PC in our network.
first it copies the pstools folder to the pc i would like to check.
It goes to pstools folder on my PC so i can start psexec.
it runs the command, show the psinfo, and then deletes the copied folder from the remote PC.
My problem is it only works if i accepted EULA manually (so started the program directly from the PC press accept when EULA message comes, and then can i use my script.)
I am trying to use the -accepteula switch but it doesn work, i still got the error message that i need to accept EULA.

Script:

```
@echo off
set ipaddress= Default
echo Enter the IP Address of the PC that you want to check:
set /p ipaddress=
echo Trying to copy PsTools file to %ipaddress%
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
robocopy \\myserver\sharedfolder\PSTools \\%ipaddress%\c$\Users\myadminuser\Downloads\PSTools
echo PsTools folder copied!
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
echo I want to start psexec from my folder, so lets go there
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
cd c:\users\myusername\downloads\pstools
echo OK, i am in my PSTools folder, time to start PsExec!
echo Let me connect to %ipaddress%
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
psexec \\%ipaddress% -u myadminuser \\%ipaddress%\c$\usersmyadminuser\Downloads\PSTools\PsInfo.exe -accepteula
echo Info gathered. Lets delete the copied PSTools folder from %ipaddress%
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
@RD /S /Q "\\%ipaddress%\c$\users\myadminuser\Downloads\PSTools\"
echo PSTools folder deleted!
pause
```

I tried to write `-accepteula` after psexec, after ipaddress, everywhere...
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 OS get LastBootupTime /format:list
```

or (this is a wrapper for the above)

```
systeminfo /s 127.0.0.1 /fo LIST | Findstr /c:"System Boot Time:"
```

None of this requires software.

Also to start programs on remote computers

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "c:\\windows\\Notepad.exe"
```

NB Programs run invisible on remote computers but visible on local computer.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that there is a easier way to do what i wanted... I made the systeminfo to a new batch file like
`@echo off
echo Check the last boot time of the PC
set ipaddress= Default
echo Enter the IP Address of the PC that you want to check:
set /p ipaddress=
systeminfo /s %ipaddress% /fo LIST | Findstr /c:"System Boot Time:"
pause`
Unfortunately on the MSInfo32 screen i dont see last boot time, or since when the pc is running, but the systeminfo is easier. Thank you again!

Comment: So its not. On the running task page you could look at the start time of CSRSS.exe.

Comment: Wow nice! Thanks! :)